# get text from SPAN element always returns null

Tags: jquery, selenium-webdriver

Below is the HTML Structure:

```
<span id="id1" class="classname1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<span class="class_2">User created successfully: Laksh Venkat</span>
```

When i try to get Text "User Created Successfully: Laksh Venkat" from the above HTML I have return with null or empty by using XPATH.

So i have tried using JQUERY And below is the code i have used:

```
String script = "return document.getElementById('id1').text";
```

But again i'm returned with Null, then i tried using .textContent, .innerHTML. But nothing is working. Any suggestion Pls??. Could you please tell me how to get the text from the above HTML. Your help is highly helpful.

thanks in Advance,

Regards

Comment: hopefully you have a closing tag for the #id1 span also

Comment: String actual = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='id1']/*[@class='class_2']")).getText();Above is the Selenium Code which i have tried. Its returning Empty String. And Also i have tried with Query (String script = "return document.getElementById('id1').getElementsByClassName('class_2').textContent";

String actual = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
)
Which is also returning empty string. Please help me